# Update Database without refresh

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Im trying to update a database field without refreshing the page

what im using is:

```
<a class="youtube" href="#" rel="<?php echo $row['link'];?>" title="<?php echo $row['title']; ?>" >
<div class="overlay_play"></div>
</a>
```

Then i want to update from this video ( they all have unique id's ofc) the field plays

My table looks like this:

id - int(9)
title - text
link - text
plays - int(99)

So in short 
I have a video list of 6 video's on one page and you can play them in a popup window
But what i want is if you click play video that the plays field will be updated

The popup window is done with jquery ( like lightbox ) so i can't refresh the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its easy ,you can do this by using ajax along with php page

```
if(playbutton pressed) {

   //perform the database operation in through calling a ajax page
   //using jquery post one of them
   $.post('ajax/save.php', function(data) {
      $('.result').html(data);
   });
}
```

**save.php**

//Contains all the database operations to save the field

Comment: Found it what i neeeded was $('.youtube-<? echo $row['id'] ;?>').click(function() {
         $.post("updateplay/save.php?&id=<? echo $row['id'] ;?>");
        });